# Expanding non-commutative terms

Tags: series-expansion

How can I expand the following equation with non-commutative terms:

```
eq = Sum[k1 (f[i + 1, j] - f[i, j]) ** (f[i + 1, 
         j] - f[i, j]), {i, 0, nx - 2}, {j, 0, ny - 1}] + 
   Sum[k2 (f[i, j + 1] -f[i, j]) ** (f[i, 
         j + 1] - f[i, j]), {i, 0, nx - 1}, {j, 0, ny - 2}];
```

where "f" is an undefined function and where nx and ny are positive nonzero integers greater than 1?

Comment: With `Distribute`?

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work because it doesn't conserve the non-commutativity of the elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform the expression with explicit rules:

```
nx = 2;
ny = 2;
eq = Sum[k1 (f[i+1,j] - f[i,j]) ** (f[i+1,j] - f[i,j]), {i, 0, nx-2}, {j, 0, ny-1}] +
     Sum[k2 (f[i,j+1] - f[i,j]) ** (f[i,j+1] - f[i,j]), {i, 0, nx-1}, {j, 0, ny-2}]
```

> k2 (-f[0, 0] + f[0, 1]) ** (-f[0, 0] + f[0, 1]) + k1 (-f[0, 0] + f[1, 0]) ** (-f[0, 0] + f[1, 0]) + k1 (-f[0, 1] + f[1, 1]) ** (-f[0, 1] + f[1, 1]) + k2 (-f[1, 0] + f[1, 1]) ** (-f[1, 0] + f[1, 1])

```
eq //. {a_ ** (b_ + c_) -> a ** b + a ** c,
        (a_ + b_) ** c_ -> a ** c + b ** c, 
        a_ ** (u_?NumericQ*b_) -> u (a ** b),
        (u_?NumericQ*a_) ** b_ -> u (a ** b)}
```

> k2 (f[0, 0] ** f[0, 0] - f[0, 0] ** f[0, 1] - f[0, 1] ** f[0, 0] + f[0, 1] ** f[0, 1]) + k1 (f[0, 0] ** f[0, 0] - f[0, 0] ** f[1, 0] - f[1, 0] ** f[0, 0] + f[1, 0] ** f[1, 0]) + k1 (f[0, 1] ** f[0, 1] - f[0, 1] ** f[1, 1] - f[1, 1] ** f[0, 1] + f[1, 1] ** f[1, 1]) + k2 (f[1, 0] ** f[1, 0] - f[1, 0] ** f[1, 1] - f[1, 1] ** f[1, 0] + f[1, 1] ** f[1, 1])

The `_?NumericQ` patterns are a bit dubious, as they will not match any other symbols (for example, they won't match `x*f[0,0]`). If you can guarantee that `f` is the only non-commutative symbol, then it may be better to replace `_?NumericQ` with `_?(FreeQ[f])`:

```
eq //. {a_ ** (b_ + c_) -> a ** b + a ** c,
        (a_ + b_) ** c_ -> a ** c + b ** c,
        a_ ** (u_?(FreeQ[f])*b_) -> u (a ** b),
        (u_?(FreeQ[f])*a_) ** b_ -> u (a ** b)}
```

> (same result)

From here on you can use the usual transformations:

```
Expand[%]
```

> k1 f[0, 0] ** f[0, 0] + k2 f[0, 0] ** f[0, 0] - k2 f[0, 0] ** f[0, 1] - k1 f[0, 0] ** f[1, 0] - k2 f[0, 1] ** f[0, 0] + k1 f[0, 1] ** f[0, 1] + k2 f[0, 1] ** f[0, 1] - k1 f[0, 1] ** f[1, 1] - k1 f[1, 0] ** f[0, 0] + k1 f[1, 0] ** f[1, 0] + k2 f[1, 0] ** f[1, 0] - k2 f[1, 0] ** f[1, 1] - k1 f[1, 1] ** f[0, 1] - k2 f[1, 1] ** f[1, 0] + k1 f[1, 1] ** f[1, 1] + k2 f[1, 1] ** f[1, 1]

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could install [FeynCalc](https://feyncalc.github.io/)

and simply do

```
Needs["FeynCalc`"]
nx = 2;
ny = 2; 
eq = 
 Sum[k1 (f[i + 1, j] - f[i, j]).(f[i + 1, j] - f[i, j]), {i, 0, 
    nx - 2}, {j, 0, ny - 1}] + 
  Sum[k2 (f[i, j + 1] - f[i, j]).(f[i, j + 1] - f[i, j]), {i, 0, 
    nx - 1}, {j, 0, ny - 2}];
DeclareNonCommutative[f];
MakeBoxes[f[a_, b_], _] := SubscriptBox["f", RowBox[{a, b}]];
Collect2[DotSimplify[eq, DotPower -> True], {k1, k2}]
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use [`TensorProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct) instead of [`NonCommutativeMultiply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply):

```
nx = 2;
ny = 2;
eq = Sum[k1 (f[i+1,j]-f[i,j])\[TensorProduct](f[i+1,j]-f[i,j]),{i,0,nx-2},{j,0,ny-1}] +
    Sum[k2 (f[i,j+1]-f[i,j])\[TensorProduct](f[i,j+1]-f[i,j]),{i,0,nx-1},{j,0,ny-2}];
```

Then:

```
TensorExpand @ eq /. TensorProduct -> CircleTimes //TeXForm
```

> $\text{k1} f(0,0)\otimes f(0,0)-\text{k1} f(0,0)\otimes f(1,0)+\text{k1} f(0,1)\otimes
>    f(0,1)-\text{k1} f(0,1)\otimes f(1,1)-\text{k1} f(1,0)\otimes f(0,0)+\text{k1}
>    f(1,0)\otimes f(1,0)-\text{k1} f(1,1)\otimes f(0,1)+\text{k1} f(1,1)\otimes
>    f(1,1)+\text{k2} f(0,0)\otimes f(0,0)-\text{k2} f(0,0)\otimes f(0,1)-\text{k2}
>    f(0,1)\otimes f(0,0)+\text{k2} f(0,1)\otimes f(0,1)+\text{k2} f(1,0)\otimes
>    f(1,0)-\text{k2} f(1,0)\otimes f(1,1)-\text{k2} f(1,1)\otimes f(1,0)+\text{k2}
>    f(1,1)\otimes f(1,1)$

where I subsituted [`CircleTimes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CircleTimes) for [`TensorProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorProduct) for readability.